# The file gets smaller after reading the jar package and writing it to another file

Tags: java, jar, java-io, outputstream

```
package com.example.demo.Util;

public class Test {

static HashMap<String,String> map = new HashMap<>();

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String data = "12j3h1i7tsa7sgdajk123y8asd: 88888";
    File jarFile = new File(new Test().getJarPath());
    File tempJar = upJarFile(jarFile, "BOOT-INF/classes/application.properties", data);
}


public static File upJarFile(File originalJarFile, String editFilePath, String content) throws IOException {
    File tempFile = File.createTempFile("temp", ".jar");
    JarFile jarFile = new JarFile(originalJarFile);
    Enumeration<JarEntry> entries = jarFile.entries();

    System.out.println("before:"+ originalJarFile.length());

    JarOutputStream jarOutputStream = new JarOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(tempFile));
    while (entries.hasMoreElements()) {
        JarEntry jarEntry = entries.nextElement();
        jarOutputStream.putNextEntry(jarEntry);
        map.put(jarEntry.getName(), String.valueOf(jarEntry.getSize()));
        jarOutputStream.write(new Test().inputStreamToByteArray(jarFile.getInputStream(jarEntry)));
    }
    jarOutputStream.finish();
    jarOutputStream.close();
    System.out.println(tempFile.getPath());

    System.out.println("after:" + tempFile.length());

    return tempFile;
}

public String getJarPath() {
    String path1 = System.getProperty("user.dir");
    File file = new File(path1 + "/target/");
    String jarFile = null;
    for (File file1 : file.listFiles()) {
        if (file1.getName().endsWith(".jar")) {
            jarFile = file1.getPath();
            break;
        }
    }
    return jarFile;
}


public byte[] inputStreamToByteArray(InputStream inputStream) {
    try (ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream()) {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int num;
        while ((num = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            byteArrayOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, num);
        }
        byteArrayOutputStream.flush();
        return byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return new byte[]{};
}

}
```

As shown in the code above,I just turn the incoming jar packages into streams and write them one by one,But it got smaller when I tested the size of the input package and the size of the output temporary package(before:49651057-->after:49647985)

What could be causing this difference?

Answer (score 1):

This can happen due to a number of reasons:

1. The original JAR file was created with a compression level that is not as high as the default compression level, so the JAR file that you create (with default compression) achieves better compression, and therefore it is smaller. You can verify this by opening both the original and the result JAR files with a ZIP utility (e.g. 7Zip) and examining their checksums and their compressed sizes. If the checksums are identical, but the compressed sizes differ, then the difference is simply due to better compression.
2. The original JAR file contains unused data. This can happen when sloppy archive creation software updates an archive by appending to it instead of rewriting it from scratch. You can verify this by opening the original ZIP archive with a ZIP utility (e.g. 7Zip) and saving it under a new filename. If the new file is smaller, then the original file contained some unused data.
3. The original JAR file contains files in subdirectories, which you are not checking. Thus, your output JAR file does not contain all of the files in the original. To fix this, you need to check each entry with `jarEntry.isDirectory()` and if so, recurse.

Comment: 1.How do I check to see if the source jar file is below the default compression level (The original jar package is generated by maven's install command)

Comment: 2.I used the size method in the jarFile API to get the source jar package and the files in the generated jar package are the same – –

Comment: @Michael I amended my answer.

Comment: I used 7zip to analyze the two jar packages and found that the files in the two jar packages had the same size, compression size and CRC, but the characteristics and offset values were different

Comment: Okay, that's interesting. I added a new #2 to the answer listing one more possible cause of the problem.

Comment: You can see that I read the source jar from scratch and then wrote it to another temporary file. I also found that the size and parameters of the processed jar package were the same before and after the processed jar package was put back into the upJarFile method above as the source JAR package

Comment: Yes, I can see that, but obviously, there is something strange in the results you are receiving, and that is why you have come to stackoverflow to ask whether there is anything wrong with what you are doing. So, I am proposing a way for you to verify that what you are doing is right, by using an external utility.

Comment: Do you have any good recommendations？

Comment: I am afraid we have a miscommunication.  Actually, on second examination of your previous comment (the one that starts with "You can see that") I must say I do not understand what you are saying there.  My recommendation was to use 7zip to do exactly what your code does, (read a jar file and save it anew,) and see whether you observe the same reduction in size. If yes, then the difference was due to unused space, and your code is fine. If not, then your code is failing to copy something.